# Why function definition is hidden from object?

Tags: typescript

Can anyone please let me know why the function declarations are hidden in JavaScript object?

```js
const obj: any = {}
obj.normal = 'normal prop'
obj.func = function(){}
console.log(obj)
```

This only returns:

```
{
  "normal": "normal prop"
}
```

However, we can access `obj.func` obviously. But my question is why the `func` property is hidden while `normal` property is not.

Ah, I just noticed that this behavior is being seen only in TypeScript. Here's the [link for the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAXDAhmAnjAvDA3gL4BQCiAdGCAE4C2aANrjAORV2MwAO1IXLpJOQBmAVzDBmYiVACW4ABQBKIsVCQQDAKbkGIAOYKySoA).

Is this a bug in TypeScript playground? Or I am missing some setting?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with typeScript playground as it is working correctly in https://www.mycompiler.io/

using same code

Comment: ah, thank you for the confirmation!

Comment: It also works in the console from chrome

Comment: Both are "working correctly", since `console.log` doesn't guarantee to show objects in any specific way; [the spec](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger) allows it to be implementation-specific.